# How to avoid overlapping geometry around corners when using Solidify?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, solidify-modifier

Let's imagine this is folded cloth:

[image]

I'd like to add some thickness to it, so I apply a Solidify modifier:

[image]

But the geometry comes across each other. I'd like to make it something like this:

[image]

This simplified case is easy to model manually, but I wonder if there is a more general way to avoid this kind of overlapping geometry caused by Solidify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because of your cuts.

If you don't have the cuts, this happens:

[image]

So one solution would be to dissolve the edges near edges.

What you could try too is to change the modifier to complex and "play" with the merge value so you can get this:

[image]
[image]